# How does $\cos(x)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$ become $\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5}{2}x\right)\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

How can you rewrite $\cos(x)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$ to $\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5}{2}x\right)\right)$?

What rules have been used? I need it on this form to compare it with a fourier series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use
$$\begin{align}
\cos a \cos b &=\frac12\left((\cos (a-b)+\cos (a+b)\right).
\end{align}$$